# Lost user permission when I change DB

Tags: mysql, sql, authentication, privileges

I have two databases where I store my data: one for run my program with italian users and one for spanish users. My code is the same and even the structure of both DB (same tables, same columns, same views...). Into the User table I have a field called FL_Abilitato where I can set two values: 1 if my user is an admin, or 2 if is a simple user.

If I run the program with the italian DB and access as an admin, everything is correct and I can see everything, but if I try the same with the spanish DB, I can't see anything.

I've already checked if the user table into both DBs are different, but I have the same columns with the same values, and I don't know where I have to look for this error. Any hints?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions to ensure the user access is the same on both DBs tables?

Comment: What kind of `permissions` are you referring to?  Are the above tables part of your application?  Your database probably has separate tables to control granting access.  Which database are you really using?  Update the question tags to show the database you're using.  Maybe this isn't an SQL issue.  It could be that you're just connecting to the wrong instance or to a database which contains no corresponding data.

Comment: @Brad yes, I have a class called Permissions.cs and through a series of breakpoints I've noticed the program do the same steps for both DB

Comment: Try connecting with the MySQL command line client to each instance / database and check the data independently.  This may just be an application mistake.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I referring of the privileges that permit to every user to see or not see a specific menu. I've updated the tags, I'm using MySql

Comment: Exactly.  Try testing those connections via the command line client.  Remove your application from the question.